# Do not match regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this regex `/\s*?left:\s*?-?\d+\.?\d*px;/im` to find for example: `left: 100.5px;`.

The problem is that it also finds `margin-left: 100px;` or `padding-left...` I want it to not match words like `-left` but match `left`.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I am using this with javascript. I have made a simple jsfiddle for this. http://jsfiddle.net/WU7GV/3/ The goal is make "jupp" appear, but not "nope" with the same regex in both if-sentences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:** Use start anchor:

```
/^left:\s*-?\d+\.?\d*px;/im
```

**Option 2:** If you cannot use start anchor as this might not be the actual start of input text then you can use word boundary with negative lookbehind like this:

```
/(?<!-)\bleft:\s*-?\d+\.?\d*px;/im
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/o1lsRU9mmE

#### Update: Javascript workaround for absence of negative lookahead:

```
var re=/\b.*?(left:\s*-?\d+\.?\d*px;)/igm;

function matchIt(str) {
   repl = str.replace(re, function($0, $1) {
      return $0 == $1? $0 : '';
   });
   return repl != ""? true : false;
}

console.log(matchIt('margin-left:100px;')); // false
console.log(matchIt('left:100px;')); // true
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/xt1kPH

Comment: It seems to be JavaScript, and AFAIK, JavaScript regex flavor does not support lookbehinds.

Comment: @sp00m: You're right Javascript doesn't support lookbehind but I really don't know if OP is using this in Javascript. Even if he does there are ways (using callback in String#replace) to achieve that.

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine! Kudos.

Comment: I am using this with javacript and i could not get ur regex to work... I have made a jsfiddle to help you understand my goal

Comment: Ok let me take look at your demo and suggest you something.

Comment: @Koiski: I updated my answer to include a workaround for Javascript. Pls check it.

Comment: @anubhava: thanx for your answer, but the fiddle you posted only workes if there is no words before "left:100px;" in the string, which in my case there is. I could not get the other solution to work either :(

Comment: Fiddle was earlier solution, latest one I posted in the answer itself in the update section.

Answer (score 2):

Use a start-of-expression anchor

```
/^\s*?left:\s*?-?\d+\.?\d*px;/im
```

There can also be metrics other than `px`, but I'm sure you know that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a beginning of string (and ending) [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), like this:

`/^\s*?left:\s*?-?\d+\.?\d*px;$/im`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Word Boundries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
[^(left)]*\b\s*?(left:\s*?-?\d+\.?\d*px;)
```

So it looks for anything that isn't 'left', a word boundry, as described in the link above. Then your ([`group`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)) to return what you want.

If you specify what language this regex is in, it'll help us answer your question. Otherwise, try out www.debuggex.com for an interactive regex debugger!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex:

```
/([^-]left|^left):.*?;/im
```

This will match in case your string begins with "left" or one that contains "left" but not "-left".

If you aren't concerned with the units of your style, .*?; is a good shorthand to match everything from : to the nearest ; .

If you need to only match px and not %;, pt;, em !important;, etc..., keep your same regex after :, although I think the non-greedy spaces:

```
\s*?
```

are unnecessary, i.e., you could just use:

```
/([^-]left|^left):\s*-?\d+\.?\d*px;/im
```